Can power enter modulus
can we say that
$|x|^n = |x^n|$ $  \forall n,x \epsilon $$R$?
for Real Numbers,
There should not be a problem since in place of x there can either be a +ve or a -ve number (since above holds true for $x=0$)
if $x > 0$, then $|x|=x$, so $|x|^n = |x^n|$ would always hold true
for $x<0$ then it should not matter if we first calculate the value of x raised to the power n and then calculate its mod or we first find the mod of x and then raise it to the power of n
if n is odd then x(viz. $< 0$) raised to the power n would be $(-1)|x|^n$ [$|x|$ is the value of $x$]
modulus of that will give $|x|^n$. Now if we first find mod of x and then raise it to the nth power even then the answer would be the same. similarly we can conclude when n is even. so by combining that can we conclude that it would hold true for all real numbers (and complex numbers too, ie. $\forall n,x \epsilon $$C$?) ?

The identity does not hold if both $n,x$ are complex. If $n=x=i$, then $|x|^n=1^i=1$, while $i^i=e^{i\log i}=e^{-\pi/2}$ (assuming the principal branch of the logarithm).

For the absolute value of real numbers, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/633642/prove-that-the-absolute-value-of-a-product-is-the-product-of-the-absolute-values and https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Absolute_Value_Function_is_Completely_Multiplicative
